# Using regex with javascript to money string transform

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a money value as `"R$ 2.200,00"` where my thousand separators are `.` and my decimal separator is `,`.

I would like um regex to transform this string into a valid MySQL decimal number.

**Possible values:**

`"R$ 23.000,20"`, `"23.000,30"`, `"R$ 1300,20"`, `"R$ 100"`, `"161,43256"`

**The results would be:**

`"23000.20"`, `"23000.30"`, `"1300.20"`, `"100"`, `"161.43256"`

My attempt is below, but it does not work. I would like to accept only numbers and dot(.) for the results.

```
const str = "R$ 2.200,000";
const res = str
  .replace(/R$/gi, "")
  .replace(/./gi, "")
  .replace(/,/gi, ".");
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Do you have to use regex? It will be much easier without it according to your possible values

Comment: I think using regex I have a small code

Comment: The problem with your regex is that "." will match any character in string, you have to escape it like that "/\./g"

Comment: OK, and How I extract only numbers, dots and comma before it

Comment: You can use parantheses to capture exact character group. Like this;   .replace(/(R\$ )/g, "")
  .replace(/\./g, "")
  .replace(/\,/g, ".")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With optimisations this seems to be working:

```js
const possible = [
  "R$ 23.000,20",
  "23.000,30",
  "R$ 1300,20",
  "R$ 100 ",
  "161,43256",
  "R$ -23.000,20",
  "-23.000,30",
  "R$ -1300,20",
  "R$ -100",
  "-161,43256"
]
const rx = /[^-\d,]+/g      // Match everything except digits, comma, dot and negative
const parseNumber = num =>
  num
  .replace(rx, '')          // Filter out non numeric entities
  .replace(',', '.')        // Replacing comma with dot

possible.forEach(num => {
  console.log(num, '\t->\t', parseNumber(num))
})
```

Comment: I have still a problem. Negative numbers are not working. Could you fix it? I need preserve negative signal

Comment: OK, I did /[^-?\d,]+/g;

Answer (score 1):

- this regEx replace/remove: (/[^\w\s]/gi) all special globaly signs ("$", ".", ","),
- next one give the digit part (/\D/g)
- and finally with string methods substring(,) place a ',' between the last two digits in the length of the string.

```js
       let input = "R$ 2.200,000"; 
        let res = input.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '') 
        let str = res.replace(/\D/g,'');
        let resStr = str.substring(0,str.length-2)+"."+str.substring(str.length-2);
        console.log(resStr)
```

Comment: Only problem with this one is it automatically assigns a decimal point with two digits to the right.

Comment: Not all of the numbers have exactly two digits after the decimal place, e.g. `161,43256`

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: However this will not work if you have more than one thousand seperator, do not use it if you may have.

So, if you don't have to use regex, you can use replace function with strings too.

```
const str = "R$ 2.200,00";
const res = str
  .replace('R$ ', "")
  .replace('.', "")
  .replace(',', ".")
console.log(res);
```

The code above will give you the format you want as a String. If you need Float, you can use parseFloat function.

```
console.log(parseFloat(res));
```

You can even use toFixed if you want absolute number of numbers after floating point

```
console.log(parseFloat(res).toFixed(5));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let input1 = "R$ 2.200,000";
let input2 = "23.000,30";
let input3 = "R$ 1300,20";
let input4 = "R$ 100";
let input5 = "161,43256";

const formatMoney = (inpStr) => {
  let res = inpStr
  res = res.replace(/[$R\s]/g, '');
  let idx = res.indexOf('.')
  res = res.replace(/,/, '.')
  for (let i in res) {
    if (res[i] === '.' && i !== i) {
      res[i] = ','
    }
  }

  return res
}

console.log(formatMoney(input1))
console.log(formatMoney(input2))
console.log(formatMoney(input3))
console.log(formatMoney(input4))
console.log(formatMoney(input5))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do that in two steps.

**Step 1: remove characters**

Substitute matches of the following regular expression with empty strings.

```
/(?:^R\$ +|[,.](?=.*[,.]))/gm
```

This will convert the strings

```
R$ 23.000,20
23.000,30
R$ 1300,20
R$ 100
161,43256
R$ 23.123.000,20
```

to

```
23000,20
23000,30
1300,20
100
161,43256
23123000,20
```

Javascript's regex engine performs the following steps.

```
(?:       : begin a non-capture groups
  ^       : beginning of string
  R\$ +   : match 'R$' followed by 1+ spaces
  |       : or
  [,.]    : match ',' or '.'
  (?=     : begin positive lookahead
    .*    : match 0+ characters other than line terminators
    [,.]  : match ',' or '.'
  )       : end positive lookahead
)         : end non-capture group
```

**Step 2: convert comma, if present, to a period**

Substitute matches of the following regular expression with a period.

```
/[,.]/gm
```

That would convert the above strings to the following.

```
23000.20
23000.30
1300.20
100
161.43256
23123000.20
```

[Restart your engine!](https://regex101.com/r/uRPUD7/2/)